# Swift Unit Test FacebookSDK issue

Tags: swift, unit-testing, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk

I have custom class that use FBSDK modules. I am trying to implement Unit Testing for this class methods. But it's cannot compile and return an error

> 'No such module FBSDKCoreKit'

I've already check this module to use by test target but nothing happens. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the problem. I need to add framework search path to test target and the issue was solved